# how to create a release certificate with java keytool using console in linux?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, keytool, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an android application where I'm using google maps. I developed this using an debug key, now I need use a release certificate but I don't know how do this, please help. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html):

> Here's an example of a Keytool command that generates a private key:
>
> $ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
> -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000

Since keytool comes with your Java installation it works the same way on Linux and Windows.

To find out the MD5 or SHA1 fingerprints of the certificates in the keystore you can use:

```
keytool -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -list
```

They are listed in the section `Certificate fingerprints`

Comment: one last question about this, in the console of google code I have that give a SHA1 certificate fingerprint of the type 45:B5:E4:6F:36:AD:0A:98:94:B4:02:66:2B:12:17:F2:56:26:A0:E0, in the private key that I generated where is this?